# scroll to the sibling element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please take a look at this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XRc5u/2/)** that shows and hides the text in a container on click . What I'm trying to do is that when I click open the first hidden text and then scroll down to click open another one, I want it to scroll back to the sibling image of that opened text to keep it in view. How can I find the sibling element and scroll to it on click?

This one is not valid.

```
  $('.slider2').click(function(e) {
   var imageposition = $(this).closest('.imageclass');
   $(document.body).animate({scrollTop: imageposition.offset().top}, 'fast');
  });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container" style="border:2px solid #222;">
  <img class="imageclass" style="width:100px;height:100px" src ="image.jpg">
  <div class="slider2"><a href="#">Hi</a></div>
  <div class="internal" style="display: block;">Text<p></p></div>
</div>

<div class="container" style="border:2px solid #222;">
  <img class="imageclass" style="width:100px;height:100px" src ="image.jpg">
  <div class="slider2"><a href="#">Hi</a></div>
  <div class="internal" style="display: block;">Text<p></p></div>
</div>
..............
```

JS:

```
$('.slider2').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();      
 $(this).next(".internal").load($(this).data("ship"));
        $('.internal').slideUp('normal');

        if ($(this).next().is(':hidden') === true) {
            $(this).addClass('on');
            $(this).next().slideDown('normal'); 
        }
     var imageposition = $(this).closest('.imageclass');
    $(document.body).animate({scrollTop: imageposition.offset().top}, 'fast'); 

 });
 $('.internal').hide();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've at least a couple of problems here

1. `$(this).closest('.imageclass')` doesn't select the image that is previous sibling of `<a>`
2. even if you get your desired image, the moment your scrolling code runs, the image has not placed itself to its final position.
3. using `$(document.body)` to scroll the window (I'm doubtful about it myself)

Below code selects the right image element, gets the scrolltop at right moment, and scrolls the `html, body` using working syntax.

```
$(function () {
    $('.slider2').click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).next(".internal").load($(this).data("ship"));
       $('.internal').slideUp('normal');
       var imageposition = $('.imageclass', $(this).closest('.container'));
       if ($(this).next().is(':hidden') === true) {
         $(this).addClass('on');
         $(this).next().slideDown('normal', function () {
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(imageposition).offset().top})
         });
      }
   });
   $('.internal').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit of a problem with how your scrolling function works because the position of the  active .container alters in relation to other containers(when active and inactive state).

Also, you should not be looking for the closest position but for its parent element.

Please take a look at my code: CSS

```
.slider2 {
    margin:40px;
}
.internal p {
    padding:5px;
}
.internal h3 {
    text-align:center;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
}
```

You might need to look for a way, to detect the height of an inactive container since I made mine as a static value.

JS:

```
$('.slider2').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next(".internal").load($(this).data("ship"));
    var containerHeight = 205;
    var containerIndex = $(this).offsetParent().index();
    $('.internal').slideUp('normal');

    if ($(this).next().is(':hidden') === true) {
        $(this).addClass('on');
        $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
    }

    var scrollPosition = containerHeight * containerIndex;
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: scrollPosition
    }, 'fast');

});
$('.internal').hide();
```